# How to handle multiple smart home devices asynchronously using node.js application?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream

I'm developing a node.js application for IOT project where the application needs to receive stream of sensor data through messaging library like zeromq and does pattern matching and anomaly detection. The challenge here is that  how to perform pattern matching and anomaly detection for multiple devices asynchronously without blocking using node.js? Node.js being event-driven, can it handle this scenario smartly by default or we need to explicitly incorporate the technique?

Comment: Do you have any samples?

Comment: It depends on your tasks for pattern matching and detection that if it's consumes cpu heavily or not. Node.js is single thread and is not good for that purpose. If you want to do with node.js maybe you need to use apache spark for heavy cpu consuming tasks